# Как правильно писать "незачто"?

Tags: орфография

"Не()за()что" - ответ, альтернативный "пожалуйста", когда человек хочет подчеркнуть, что услуга не стоит благодарности. Но вот никак не могу взять в толк, как правильно писать это слово. Тут имеется и отрицательная частица, и приставка (или предлог), то есть слово получилось "трехэтажное".
Так как его писать: слитно, в два слова или в три слова?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При выборе формы написания  слов надо провести грамматический анализ: что - за что (падежная форма) - не за что (отрицание). Формы "зачто" не существует.

Мы можем сказать: За что тебя благодарить? Не за что.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: не за что.